# ¿Cómo hacer un DIV flotante a la derecha con Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo la siguiente estructura de HTML con Bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
     Aqui hay tanto contenido que el scrollbar se va hasta China
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div> 
            Este debe mantenerse flotando a la derecha de manera fija, asi el scroll llegue al piso.
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Al usar `position:fixed` en el `div` con la clase `col-md-3`, se va a la izquierda y se pone sobre el contenido del `div col-md-9`. Utilice el affix de Bootstrap y no me dio resultado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La clase `col-md-3` de bootstrap ya posiciona el `div` a la derecha gracias al sistema de cuadrícula de bootstrap. No es recomendable asignarle clases para flotarlo o posicionarlo fijamente, pero si puedes hacer esto con el `<div>` interno.

Para lograr lo que buscas sólo agrega `style="position: fixed;"` al `<div>` interno.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    Aqui hay tanto contenido que el scrollbar se va hasta China
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div style="position: fixed;">
      Este debe mantenerse flotando a la derecha de manera fija, asi el scroll llegue al piso.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin utilizar otras clases o plugins de 'bootstrap', quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9">
      Aqui hay tanto contenido que el scrollbar se va hasta China
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div style="position:fixed;left:79.1%;"> 
      Este debe mantenerse flotando a la derecha de manera fija, asi el scroll llegue al piso.
        </div>  
     </div>
</div>
```

Espero les haya sido de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a posicionar el div hacia la derecha de un contenedor cómo si usaras `float:right:` usa la clase `.pull-right`.

O si por el contrario quieres mantener siempre el div hacia la derecha con un a posición fija prueba lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
     Aqui hay tanto contenido que el scrollbar se va hasta China
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="position: fixed;right: 0;z-index:9999">
        <div> 
            Este debe mantenerse flotando a la derecha de manera fija, asi el scroll llegue al piso.
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Agregando al `<div>` que quieres fijar el siguiente estilo: `style="position: fixed;right: 0;z-index:9999"`